# Shortcut key for Emmet "wrap with abbreviation" in Sublime 2 on OSX?

Tags: html, sublimetext2, sublimetext, emmet

I installed Emmet on Sublime2 on OSX. I want to use the "Wrap with Abbreviation" feature. There's a lot of conflicting information about what the shortcut should be, and I've tried every option, but nothing seems to work.

- `ctrl` + `w`
- `cmd` + `w`
- `cmd` + `shift`+ `w`
- `shift` + `cmd` + `a`
- `shift` + `ctrl` + `g`

Nothing works. The closest I get is with `shift` + `cmd` + `a`, which wraps a bunch of things with `<p>` tags in various lines throughout the document. That's cool but it's not what I'm going for. Is there an up to date reference of keybindings for Emmet on Sublime2?

Comment: https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime#available-actions

Comment: Yeah saw that, the keybindings indicated there (`ctrl` + `w`, `shift` + `ctrl` + `g` ) don't work.

Comment: @AndyHolmes That closes the tab.

Comment: @brentonstrine i had the same issue and i'm trying to remember it. I work with Windows at work, but Mac at home haha

Comment: Seems crazy the information out there is all wrong. Isn't OSX + Sublime + Emmet one of the most common combos for web developers? You'd think that all the documentation would mention this combo.

Comment: How odd, on my Mac it's just `ctrl` + `w`. This is SublimeText2 and I'm using default keybindings. One thing, I do believe you do need to make sure the selected syntax is something other than plain text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ctrl` + `shift` + `w` on OSX is what you're after I believe

Comment: That's the magic combo. Thanks! Did you just remember or do you have some source you used that's accurate?

Comment: I got my macbook out my bag and tried it ;) haha - remembered it straight away. I knew i had the same issue in the beginning, took me a while to work it out too

Comment: Default OSX keybinding is `Ctrl+W`: https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime/blob/master/Default%20(OSX).sublime-keymap#L269
Everything else means someone or something (another plugin) redefined it. You should check your User keymap file

Comment: @SergeyChikuyonok your answer is the correct one for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use this shortcut on windows 10

```
alt+shift+w = abbreviation
```

example:
**Eu sou lindo >> select this phrase then click in alt+shif+w**

result

```
<p>Eu sou lindo</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Preferences > Package Settings > Emmet > Key Bindings

Copy Emmet Key Bindings to your Custom Key Bindings